# How can I find the characteristic function in this question?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

This is a question from my university list:

> Let $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ be statistically independent and identically distributed random variables, each with an exponential probability density function of parameter $1$, that is:
>   $$
> p_{x_i} (X)=a \cdot e^{-aX} u(X) \quad ,\,i=1,2,\ldots
> $$
>
> Let $n$ be a discrete random variable statistically independent of each $x_i$, with a probability density function given by
>   $$
> p_n (N)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-1}}{k!} δ(N-k).
> $$
>
> Set the random variable
>   $$
> y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i
> $$
>   where, by definition, $y = 0$ if $n = 0$. Determine:
>
> a) the characteristic function $M_y(v)$;

However, I can't solve this problem problem, I found this solution:

$$M_y = \frac{1}{(a-j \cdot v)^{n}}$$

I don't know how to eliminate the random variable "$n$" from the equation and get a expression that only depends on from v(My(v)). Could someone help me how to complete the solving of this problem???

Comment: Please typeset using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @StubbornAtom  Forgive me , I'm pretty new here.  it's done,  now the post  maybe the post is more legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the definition of the characteristic function and separate the instances of expectation values for $n$ and $x_i$ to obtain:

$$M_y(v)=\mathbb{E}[e^{ivy}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{iv\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}}]=\mathbb{E_n[E_{x_i}}[\prod_{i=1}^ne^{iv{x_i}}]]=\mathbb{E}_n[(\mathbb{E_x}[e^{ivx}])^n]$$

However

$$M_x(v)=\mathbb{E}[e^{ivx}]=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ivx}ae^{-ax}dx=\frac{a}{a-iv}$$

and now all that's left is to compute the expectation over the state space of the $n$ variable:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}_n[(M_x(v))^n]&=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}(M_x(v))^N\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ek!}\delta(N-k)\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ek!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(M_x(v))^N\delta(N-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e}\frac{(M_x(v))^k}{k!}\\&=e^{M_x(v)-1}\end{align}$$

and hence we find that

$$M_y(v)=\exp\Big(\frac{iv}{a-iv}\Big)$$

EDIT: Explanation of the first line

Note that the variables $x_1,...,x_n,n$ are independent. This allows us to construct the joint probability distribution

$$f(X_1,..., X_N,N)=p_n(N)\prod_{i=1}^N p_{x_i}(X_i)$$

We can easily see that this is a distribution since trivially

$$\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}\int~\prod_{i=1}^N ~dX_i~f(X_1,..,X_N,N)=1$$

It is indeed a funny looking distribution, because it's state space varies with $N$, and hence that variable has to be chosen first! Nevertheless, with this expression we can compute expectation values like the characteristic function:

$$M_y(v)=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}p_n(N)\prod_{i=1}^N dX_i \exp(iv\sum_{k=1}^N X_k)f(\{X_i\},N)=\mathbb{E}_N[\mathbb{E}_{\{x_i\}}[e^{iv\sum x_i}]]\\=\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}p_n(N)\Big(\int_{0}^{\infty} dXe^{itX}p_x(X)\Big)^N=\mathbb{E}_N[(M_x(v))^N]$$

The reason why the first line in the equation above is true is essentially because we can pull out $p_n(N)$ because the variables are independent, and view what's left as an expectation value taken over the rest of the variables.

Comment: your solution is good, and I understand almost everything. But I one point I have a little doubt, do you have some reference for this property E[eiv∑ni=1xi]=En[Exi[∏i=1neivxi]]??? it's in the first formula, mathjax doesn't work in the comments

Comment: This is a good point which I will adress with an edit.

Comment: Nice, it's corrects, thanks!. But one point, I think there's a little mistake in the first integral, there's not that fator (1/a) in the first integral, when you calculated the Mx(v). But the main idea is correct.

Comment: That $a$ has to exist, otherwise the distribution is not normalized. If a=1 in your problem, then you can set it equal to $1$.

Comment: so sorry, the mistake was mine. I forget the $$a$$ in this formula, it should be $$p_{x_i} (X)= a \cdot e^{-aX} u(X) \quad ,\,i=1,2,\ldots$$

Comment: yea it should be correct now